# IDE to program Arduino Uno especially internal interrupt vectors

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, interrupt, ide, atmel-studio

I am trying to program this Arduino Uno's Timer1 module to use its Input Capture pin to record the times of edges and store / transmit them during the Input Capture Interupt Service Routine, but I cannot find documentation on how to program the guts of this Arduino Uno?

What IDE do people use to do advanced things with their Arduinos? I am trying to use Atmel Studio 6 after I gave up using the Arduino IDE and now I'm trying to use Visual Micro plug-in for visual studio.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do all you need to do in the Arduino IDE.  It doesn't "block" you from doing any low-level operations.  Any other IDE will also allow you to do what you want.

All the information you need to manipulate the "guts" of the Arduino is the datasheet for the main chip - the ATMega328P on the Uno.

http://www.atmel.com/images/atmel-8271-8-bit-avr-microcontroller-atmega48a-48pa-88a-88pa-168a-168pa-328-328p_datasheet.pdf

Comment: Ah yes. For some reason I thought my chip was an Atmega16U2, which doesn't have interrupt vector names for its interrupts in its documentation. The documentation for the 328P actually has everything. Thank you for making me realize my mistake.